# Getting the $_SESSION empty after filling with data from DB

Tags: php, html, rest, google-chrome, zoho

I'm making an integration between two apis, what the api makes is to take information from one site to add it in another site in one way api conection. 
As a first step the program should enter to the PART1 of the view.php file, then is comes to the fill.php I insert some information to the database and then fill the $_SESSION with some information.

fill.php

```
        try{
            $DB_ = new PDO("mysql:host={$GLOBALS['db_host']};dbname=$GLOBALS['database']};
        charset=utf8",$GLOBALS['db_user'],$GLOBALS['db_password']);

        $query = $DB_->query("INSERT into users (User1, 
        Pass1, User2, Pass2, status) VALUES 
         ('".$GLOBALS['User1']."', '".$jsonResponse["Pass1"]."', 
         null, null, 1)");

        if(is_numeric($DB_->lastInsertId()) == TRUE){
            $_SESSION['ID'] = $DB_->lastInsertId();
            $_SESSION['User1'] = $GLOBALS['User1'];
            $_SESSION['Pass1'] = $jsonResponse["Pass1"];
            $DB_ = null;
        }else{
            echo "Las variables de sesion no fueron seteadas correctamente";
            $DB_ = null;
        }

    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Ha ocurrido un error al momento de insertar una información.";
        die();
    }
```

Then I come back again to view.php and I should enter to the PART 2 of the view because now the $_SESSION['ID'] is set with some numeric value. But it's not working on Chrome, for some reason in Edge and Firefox works bus in chrome it is not.

view.php

```
  <?php 
        if(!isset($_SESSION['ID'])){   //PART 1
                echo '<div class="alert alert-warning"> 
                        <strong>its not sync, click over here </strong><a class="green-link" href="./create-account.php" target="_blank"> CLICK.</a>
                     </div>';

            }
        ?>
        <div id="status-message">
            <!-- Contenido cargado a través de javascript -->
        </div>
        <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION['ID'])){  //PART 2
                echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">
                        <strong>Its sync now</strong> <a class="green-link" href="https://'.$_SESSION['someurl'].'" target="_blank"> CLICK</a>
                     </div>';
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: Also, not sure what you are asking, but looking at your code, you have a syntax error on `It's`, the `'` should be escaped...

Comment: I refactored my question fellows